# Siddur Tehilas Hashem - Yiddish

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, chabad, yiddish

Does anyone know where I might find the common Chabad siddur, Siddur Tehilas Hashem, with a Yiddish translation? A while back I had seen one for sale on Eichler's website, but the link has since been taken down. It is important that I can buy it online.

---

I tried eBay, Reb Google, etc. All to no avail.

Comment: Why don't you try writing to a Chabad publishing house or educational resource centre?

Comment: I forget what it is called by there is a siddur (not korbon mincha) that is hebrew with an interlinear yiddish translation. I could not find it on the kehot website but you might be able to find it at their physical store or other chabad Judaica stores. It is an older siddur that isn't often used so it's possible to be out of print as well.

Comment: @Laser123 - See the second link in the answer below.

Comment: If you're ok with another (but similar) version of nusach Ari, you can definitely find it in Yiddish. I think they also call those Korban Minchah, not sure. Go to a chassidish bookstore and look for the stuff with pretty covers. I have a Yiddish siddur that is in Nusach Ashkenaz, I think, called ליניען־סדור, compiled by Joseph Magil in 1904 (mine is 1921)

Comment: @SAH - Like [this one](http://seforimcenter.com/YIDDISH-Books/Siddur-Tefillah-BeKavanah--Sefard-Hebrew-/-Yiddish__p-317-5554.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from Kehot Publishing. It is called Siddur Korban Mincha. The prayers are not in Yiddish, but it has a running Yiddish commentary. It is according to nusach Chabad.

http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HP-SKM

Additionally,this is the siddur Tehilat HaShem translated to Yiddish at hebrewbooks.org. You could download the PDF or read it online. It seems that no one has order a print version yet. That may be for copywrite limitations.

http://hebrewbooks.org/53078

Comment: Kehos sell the pirush Hamilos in Yiddish