# Yiddish Siddur (Nusach Ashkenaz)

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, yiddish

I am trying to buy a new Yiddish siddur, but all the ones I see available are nusach Sefard. I wonder if anybody has a recommendation of where one might be able to find a Yiddish siddur which is Nusach Ashkenaz?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81592/siddur-tehilas-hashem-yiddish

Answer (score 1):

I only know of one, but you're not going to find a modern print of it. It has been out of print for a century now. [Reb Yehudah Leib Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Leib_Gordon) printed a Nusach Ashkenaz siddur with a Yiddish translation called [סדור בית יהודה](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94.html?id=k_jitgAACAAJ), originally in Vilna. Sometimes you can find a copy of it for sale online. For example, [here's one](https://www.virtualjudaica.com/Listing/Details/1607389/Siddur-Bet-Yehuda-R-Yehuda-Leib-Gordin-New-York-1921) that was auctioned off.

The primary speakers of Yiddish are Hasidim, who use Nusach Sfard, or secular people who use no siddur at all. There isn't much of a market for a Nusach Ashkenaz siddur in Yiddish nowadays.

If you're interested, [here is a copy for sale on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/392829003383?hash=item5b766ee677:g:OxYAAOSwSK5e3L0o&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoMa8HU9jK5PMiSjub5mSK%2Bi4LmhSAOdL422JMfn8azkNeQ9rTc4oOZ2MRgYY0xiQTp%2BsLsRJsgtTeDREZ%2B%2FDFoVQ6itFvp2VnMfFWj%2BEzvOzRiFd0o0LoJ905pdkfY872yEgHyhpq7o85zoWbEdujyXArlahP6DGhWZi%2FmIDeE1tHueNjIqMDz9bqws39u8%2BKH6h1d7fxoMUZv%2BaI%2FlFzJI%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5qNx8T8YA) right now from Mizrahi Bookstore.